# SharedPreferences into a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, sharedpreferences

I need to load my preferences.xml file based on SharedPreferences into a ViewPager.
I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
```

I was searching for a solution but I can't found anything. What can I do?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private CustomViewPager customViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        customViewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        customViewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter());
        customViewPager.setPageMargin(0);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
    }

    private class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
            RelativeLayout viewLayout = null;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) viewGroup.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            switch (position) {

            case 0:
                viewLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_meetings, null);
                viewGroup.addView(viewLayout, 0);
                break;

            case 1:
                viewLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings, null);
                viewGroup.addView(viewLayout, 0);

                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new FragmentPreferences()).commit();
                break;
            }
            customViewPager.setObjectForPosition(viewLayout, position);
            return viewLayout;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }
    }

    public static class FragmentPreferences extends PreferenceFragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings, null);
            // return view;

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ListPreference
        android:key="speed_setting"
        android:title="@string/speed_setting_title"
        android:summary="@string/speed_setting_description"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/speed_setting_title"
        android:entries="@array/speed_setting_entry_labels"
        android:entryValues="@array/speed_setting_entry_labels"
        android:defaultValue="@string/speed_setting_default_value"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_list_speed_setting" />
    <ListPreference
        android:key="permission_type_setting"
        android:title="@string/permission_type_setting_title"
        android:summary="@string/permission_type_setting_description"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/permission_type_setting_title"
        android:entries="@array/permission_type_setting_entry_labels"
        android:entryValues="@array/permission_type_setting_entry_labels"
        android:defaultValue="@string/permission_type_setting_default_value"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_list_permission_type_setting" />
    <ListPreference
        android:key="sensibility_setting"
        android:title="@string/sensibility_setting_title"
        android:summary="@string/sensibility_setting_description"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/sensibility_setting_title"
        android:entries="@array/sensibility_setting_entry_labels"
        android:entryValues="@array/sensibility_setting_entry_labels"
        android:defaultValue="@string/sensibility_setting_default_value"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_list_sensibility_setting" />
    <ListPreference
        android:key="time_format_setting"
        android:title="@string/time_format_setting_title"
        android:summary="@string/time_format_setting_description"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/time_format_setting_title"
        android:entries="@array/time_format_setting_entry_labels"
        android:entryValues="@array/time_format_setting_entry_labels"
        android:defaultValue="@string/time_format_setting_default_value"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_list_time_format_setting" />
    <ListPreference
        android:key="maps_setting"
        android:title="@string/maps_setting_title"
        android:summary="@string/maps_setting_description"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/maps_setting_title"
        android:entries="@array/maps_setting_entry_labels"
        android:entryValues="@array/maps_setting_entry_labels"
        android:defaultValue="@string/maps_setting_default_value"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_list_maps_setting" />
    <ListPreference
        android:key="resource_consumption_setting"
        android:title="@string/resource_consumption_setting_title"
        android:summary="@string/resource_consumption_setting_description"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/resource_consumption_setting_title"
        android:entries="@array/resource_consumption_setting_entry_labels"
        android:entryValues="@array/resource_consumption_setting_entry_labels"
        android:defaultValue="@string/resource_consumption_setting_default_value"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_list_resource_consumption_setting" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: customViewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);, Where you are setting the contentView for this Activity.

Comment: Excuse me Rajesh CP I forget to put the lines where I set the contentView. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html). But it is only available after api level 11. You can find the details with clear example in the link

Comment: Excuse me. I don't know how to do it with SharedPreferences